# PHP public getter / setter not seen by symfony serialize

Tags: php, class, symfony, serialization, getter-setter

Ive made a class that stores columns and rows these 2 are both arrays who both have extra data, like this:

```
<?php
class Table{
    private array $Columns = array();
    private array $Rows = array();
    public function setColumn(Columns $c)
    {
        array_push($this->Columns, $c);
    }
    public function getColumn(): array
    {
        return $this->Columns;
    }
    public function setRow(Rows $c)
    {
        array_push($this->Rows, $c);
    }
    public function getRow(): array
    {
        return $this->Rows;
    }
}
class Columns{
   public string $Someinfo;
   public function setSomeinfo(string $c)
    {
        $this->Someinfo= $c;
    }
    public function getSomeinfo(): int
    {
        return $this->Someinfo;
    }
}
class Rows{
   public string $Someinfo;
      public function setSomeinfo(string $c)
    {
        $this->Someinfo= $c;
    }
    public function getSomeinfo(): int
    {
        return $this->Someinfo;
    }
}
?>
```

My Symfony serializer sees and uses this class when its public but when I turn it private it suddenly stops working.

Symfony serializer:

```
$serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()], [new JsonEncoder()]);
        return $serializer->deserialize($data, $table, 'json');
```

Ive tried almost all types of set, get and adders but none works or gets triggered by the serializer. The documentation has some examples but they are the same as my code at chapter: Deserializing a object.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#component-serializer-attributes-groups

Comment: Getters and setters should follow property names. So for a property called `$Columns` it would expect `getColumns` and `setColumns`. If you try that, does it detect them then?

Comment: Try using property names that begin with a lowercase. You may be confusing the property accessor by creating a property `SomeInfo` instead of `someInfo`.

Comment: @El_Vanja I already got a Table::setColumns error so now it gets initialized. Thanks for the help!!